# Where is my "stdio.h" in Mac?

Tags: c, macos

I know that Mac OS X is a Unix-based system. And I heard that C standard library such as stdio.h, is located in `/usr/local/include` or `/usr/include`. But there is not any kind of library in this directory. I use Terminal to search this directory and I also use command like `find ./ -iname "stdio.h"`, but nothing comes out. However, strangely enough, `gcc -test.c -o test` command works out. How did it happen? I want to know where my C library is located.
p.s I also use Xcode, too. Is it related with this application? help me!
    And I have AWS EC2 linux server, and it has both libraries that i refereed above.

Comment: The `<stdio.h>` header file is part of the C standard library, and may be in *any* directory that the compiler searches for header files, it may be in a sub-directory to `/usr/lib` for example. Also, the command `find ./ -iname "stdio.h"` search for the file from the *current* directory, so if you're in e.g. your own home-directory you will not find the file.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you have Xcode but have not installed the optional Command Line Tools package then the standard includes and libraries may not be found in the usual place. Try:

```
$ find /Applications/Xcode.app -name stdio.h
```

and you'll probably see something like:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/sys/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/include/sys/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/sys/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/sys/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h
```

However you might want to ***install the Command Line Tools package if you plan on doing any non-Xcode (i.e. command line) programming***. You will then see the usual headers and libraries in `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib`.

Comment: Thanks. But after i installed command line tools, only /usr/include have library file. there is no "/usr/local/include" !! which means, when i type "cd /usr/local/include", error comes out : No such file or directory. is it ok ??

Comment: @user3595632 That's fine, `/usr/local` is traditionally used by add-on SDKs and packages, not by the platform vendor.

Comment: That's right - /usr/local is for installing third party stuff so that it doesn't get overwritten when you update the system. System stuff goes in /usr.

Comment: I don't know what I've installed but `find $(xcode-select --print-path) -name stdio.h` gives me the location. (there's no xcode gui for sure but there's no `/usr/include/`)

Answer (score 29):

If you don't have Command Line Tools installed you can run:

```
xcode-select --install
```

A dialogue box opens for you to accept the license agreement and so on.

(This was missing from the above responses.)

Answer (score 13):

create/update a symlink for `/usr/include` to have the libs detected:

```
sudo ln -sf /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include /usr/include
```

The above path can be found by searching for stdio.h

```
find /Applications/Xcode.app -path '*/usr/include/stdio.h'
```

---

I have to do this with every XCode/MacOS SDK update, Faced this today with the XCode 7 upgrade.

Once the command line tools are installed, they cannot be re-installed with `xcode-select`, so the path may not be updated with a Mac AppStore upgrade.

Uninstalling & Reinstalling XCode and then running `xcode-select --install` might update the path, but is an overkill.

Some posts also mention `xcode-select --switch /Application/Xcode.app`, but I didn't have much luck with it.

Comment: Apple no longer allows you to do this: `ln: /usr/include: Operation not permitted`. (And yes, I did try it with `sudo`, and yes, I do have the password.)

Answer (score 5):

The root reason is missing the /usr/include folder, installing command-line tools sometimes will not automatically add it.

Install the package at

/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg

Comment: I am on MacOS Mojave, but I am not able to find this `Packages` directory under `CommandLineTools`.

Comment: Yes, I did install the comand line tool, but there is no such package. Anyway, asked my colleague to share the package with me.

Comment: if /usr/include still not exist after install CommandLineTools, can create a link by run commad sudo ln -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/ /usr/include

Comment: @jolestar When I try to make that link. MacOS replies, `ln: /usr/include: Operation not permitted`. Yes, I tried `sudo`, and yes, I know the password.

Comment: @JohnPerry it is a new macOS security limit.

Answer (score 2):

In my laptop it appears in many locations like `/usr/include/stdio.h` and `/usr/include/sys/stdio.h` and `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h`.

Answer (score 2):

If you already built your locate database, you can use

```
locate stdio.h
```

If you haven't already, build it. The `locate` command [is awesome](http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/02/enable-and-use-the-locate-command-in-the-mac-os-x-terminal/)!

Answer (score 1):

Due to Apple's new System Integrity Protection (SIP), you will run into this error when attempting the solution of creating/updating a symlink to `/usr/include`

`ln: /usr/include: Operation not permitted`

Instead of disabling SIP, the better way to do it is to create symlinks in `/usr/local/include` instead, e.g.

`ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/* /usr/local/include/`

This works for people who have already installed CommandLineTools and was unable to find `stdio.h` inside `/usr/include`

Answer (score 1):

This is my path for C/C++ library in M1 Mac 2022

/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1

Answer (score 0):

In the folder

```
Applications/Xcode/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include
```

or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed "CommandLineTools", and the "stdio.h" file exist in both Xcode and CommandLineTools diretory.

/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h